# How to find out those users which have two different access right in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Thanks for your support and help,
Dear the scenario is like this i have 3 tables

```
1: users
2: users_groups
3: users_groups_rel
```

users data

```
id      name
1       zubair
2       ali
3       bob
4       john
```

users_groups data

```
   id    name
    1   report
    2   finance
    3   personnel
```

users_groups_rel data; it is associated table of users and users_groups

```
 uid    gid
    1   1
    1   2
    1   3
    2   3
    3   2
    4   2
    4   1
```

> Now i want to have those users which have access just to (Report +
>   finance) When i am running this bellow query the result is incorrect,
>   it shows those users which have id of (1 , 4) but i don’t need this i
>   need that users which mentioned the exact access right for them.
>
> example:
>   i need those users which have access to these access right
>   (report and finance)

---

```
SELECT r.uid,u.name
   FROM users_groups_rel r left join users u on u.id=r.uid
   GROUP BY r.uid,u.name
   HAVING count(DISTINCT gid in (select id from users_groups where id=2)) = (SELECT count(DISTINCT gid in (select id from users_groups where id=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate and check if the distinct count per user is equal to the count of distinct groups of the whole table.

Assuming that the user is identified by a column `user_id` and the group by a column `group_name`.

```
SELECT user_id
       FROM users_group
       GROUP BY user_id
       HAVING count(DISTINCT group_name) = (SELECT count(DISTINCT group_name)
                                                   FROM user_group);
```

Comment: Dear stiky please see the scenario which i edit and need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_agg and compare it with the desired conditions:

```
SELECT
    uid, array_agg(gid ORDER BY uid, gid) grp
FROM
    users_groups_rel
GROUP BY
    uid;
```

```
uid | grp    
--: | :------
  1 | {1,2,3}
  2 | {3}    
  3 | {2}    
  4 | {1,2}    -- reports and finances only
```

```
SELECT
    uid
FROM
    users_groups_rel
GROUP BY
    uid
HAVING array_agg(gid ORDER BY uid, gid) = ARRAY[1, 2];
```

```
| uid |
| --: |
|   4 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=86db76b3db8ed10beded767861d10dce)*

**Update**

If you want to use group's name instead of id's you can use next query:

```
SELECT
    ugr.uid
FROM
    users_groups_rel ugr
JOIN
    users_groups ug
    ON ug.id = gid
GROUP BY
    uid
HAVING 
    array_agg(ug.name::text ORDER BY ugr.uid, ugr.gid) = ARRAY['report', 'finance'];
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6e839fb6147eae46aefdc5427a55bcba)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your corporation Mr.McNets,the query which you added that is completely fine, but i have another question regarding this (i have 100+ access right now i want to use the group names instead of group id how should i used your query.

Comment: Dear when i run this query into my real DB i faced to this (ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] = text[]
LINE 11: ...   array_agg(rg.name ORDER BY rugr.uid, rugr.gid) = ARRAY['A...
                                                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
)

Comment: What data type is `name` ?

Comment: The data type is character varying

Comment: Then cast name as text `name::text`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6e839fb6147eae46aefdc5427a55bcba

Comment: Dear McNets Thanks for your support,but now i am not facing to any error when i am running the mentioned query but the result of the query is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one attempt. Note that you must have unique constraints on group.name for this to work:

```
select u.id, u.name 
from users u 
join user_groups_rel r 
    on u.id = r.uid 
join user_groups g 
    on r.gid = g.id 
group by u.id, u.name 
having count(distinct case when g.name in ('report','finance')
                           then g.id 
                      end
            ) = 2 
   and count(distinct g.id) = 2
```

In short, which users are members of exactly 2 groups and also members of exactly 2 groups among report and finance.

If you are only interested in the id of the user, you can remove the user table, and adjust the query accordingly.

Some notes on naming conventions, don't use vague identifiers like id. Use for example user_id, and stick with that in related tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users
( user_id int not null primary key
, user_name varchar(20) not null
);

CREATE TABLE groups
( group_id int not null primary key
, group_name varchar(20) not null unique
);

CREATE TABLE user_groups
( user_id int not null references users (user_id)
, group_id int not null references groups (group_id)
,    primary key (user_id, group_id)
);
```